# Pagination of generic table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pagination

Let's say I am writing a query template to query any table in a PostgreSQL 14 database.  The template takes 3 inputs:

```
table_name, page_number, rows_per_page
```

And looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <table_name> 
LIMIT <rows_per_page> OFFSET (<page_number> -1)*<rows_per_page>
```

The problem with the above 'pagination' is that it is unreliable, Postgres doc says that without ORDER BY clause will produce inconsistent results. My question is: is there a way to remedy this problem for a generic table i.e. a table that has no known way to order it (no primary key)? Basically what I am asking is: is there any 'hidden' ordering that Postgres is using and I can access through a query or the tables that have no primary key are inherently unordered?

Comment: Why not extend your template to include the column names to be used for the ORDER BY